# CSS: Align table to top

Tags: html, css

I have a page with the container in a table I need to align it to the topmost of the page, but there is a gap. Also need to center the page horizontally.

I tried

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: You need to show more code or (better)  a live link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
html, body {
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

table {
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: This aperently centered the table but there is still a gap on top.

Comment: Does your table reside in a `<form>`, a `<div>` or another container?

Comment: Only tables, no div nor forms.

Comment: Check your first row of cells, you might have some `border`, `margin` or `padding` set on your `<th>` or `<td>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

This might work.

```
* {margin:0; padding:0;}

table#idName {
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the first child element of the div? Have you zeroed the top margin on that element (or given the div a small top padding or border)?